# Disabling Text Boxes and DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, textbox

I'm working on a windows WinForm. I need to prevent further editing of textBox and also columns inside the DataGridView.

I want all this to happen only if a function returns value true.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static bool isAuthSuccess = false;
```

Comment: I've just removed the word webform from the question text since everything else indicates that this is winforms.

Comment: So you want to set a textbox and some datagridview columns to readonly based on the return value of a function? What causes that function to be run? Provide some code to show what you have so far.

Comment: public static bool isAuthSuccess = false;    This Is wat i have declared in the variable part

Comment: If(isAuthSuccess) ....I want to Prevent further Editing  textBox and Grid

Comment: Where do you set isAuthSuccess - why can't you just set the textbox and columns to readonly there?

Comment: A word of advice, Lijina: give answers helpful answers upvotes and accept correct ones. 40% will get you many angry glares. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//if function() returns true
if(function())
{
    textbox1.ReadOnly = true;
    datagridview1.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

or with your variable:

```
if(isAuthSuccess)
{
    textbox1.ReadOnly = true;
    datagridview1.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Is this all you're asking for? This will allow you to view but not change anything. Just flip them back to false when you want to edit again.

Comment: I tried this Answer...But Thing is my datagridview has got scroll bars for it..so when i make it readonly..what actually happens is the scroll bars is not serving itzz purpose...i want the scroll bars of the datagridview to function Properly..even if it is made readonly  -----@Yatrix

Comment: Really? Are you sure you didn't disable it? I just tested this and it scrolled fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent further editing, I assume the user will be editing it and when they are done you want to check the state against this function.

If that is the case then you can call this function in the validation by validating the textbox and datagridview.

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) can help you with the case of winforms.

Comment: The question is about winforms, not webforms

Comment: Or at least the tags say winforms and it mentions datagridview - was just editing the question and noticed 'webforms'

Comment: It says windows web form... which I am assuming is not winforms.

Comment: Yes, hard to be sure - the tags and the datagridview control all indicate winforms however. My guess is the webform in the question text is incorrect.